# Relation between Segmentation fault and Struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, scanf

I got some `Segmentation fault` when I try to `scanf` numbers to a struct.
I don't know if is it a relation between `scanf` and the fault in this case or not.
I think I allocated well the memory, I read In past 2 hours about this fault, and everywhere I read about memory allocate problems, but I don't see this in my code.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80
#define PHONE_NUMBER 15

struct order {
    time_t   systime;
    char     name[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char     email[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int      phonenumber;
    int      size;    
};


//functions
void readName(struct order *current);
void checkValues(struct order *current);
void readEmail(struct order *current);
void readPhone(struct order *current);
void readSize(struct order *current);

//read name
void readName(struct order *current){
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%80[^\n]", current->name);
   // scanf("%s",current->name);
}

//read email
void readEmail(struct order *current){
    printf("e-mail: ");
    char tmp[80];
    scanf("%s[^\n]",current->email);
}

//read phone number
void readPhone(struct order *current){
    printf("phone: ");
    scanf("%15i[^\n]", current->phonenumber);
}

//read size of order
void readSize(struct order *current){
    printf("size: ");
    scanf("%i", current->size);
}

void checkValues(struct order *current){
    printf("Name: %s \n",current->name);
    printf("e-mail: %s \n", current->email);
    printf("tel: %d \n", current->phonenumber);
    printf("size: %d \n", current->size);
    printf("time: %ld \n", current->systime);
}

//***

int main(k)
{
   struct order current; //struct init

   //read values
   readName(&current);
   readEmail(&current); 
   readPhone(&current); // I got the error here, but only if I try this with numbers, with letters save only 0
   readSize(&current);
   current.systime = time(NULL);

   // ** //
    checkValues(&current);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your `readPhone` function, are you trying to read a string or an integer? And for reading integers, what is the argument you need to pass to `scanf`?

Comment: Please enable warnings; they can help you with `scanf` format mismatches. Whenever you scan something other than strings with `%s` or `%[`, you must pass the address of the variable you store the result in. So it's `scanf("%i", &current->size)` and so on.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to save phone numbers, so max 15 number length integers

Comment: @MOehm yes, this helped me, please write it as an answer and then I can accept it

Comment: In general, you're better off using numeric types (e.g. int) for numbers that you want to compute, like age or price or quantity.  Numbers that are really labels -- such as phone numbers or street numbers -- are better kept as strings.  That way, you capture the exact representation, and lose nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `scanf("%15i[^\n]", current->phonenumber);`

As already pointed out, this should be:

```
scanf("%15i", &current->phonenumber);
```

(you repeated the same mistake in `readSize` as well.)

In general, you should compile with *maximum* warnings available for your compiler. A good compiler will warn you that you are passing an `int` to `scanf` when a pointer is expected.

> I want to save phone numbers, so max 15 number length integers

On a typical system, `sizeof(current->phonenumber) == 4`. That means that the highest value you can store in that variable is `INT_MAX == 2147483647`. That's only 10 digits, and *not every* 10-digit number will fit.

If you want to be able to store every possible 15-digit number, you need to store them differently (in `char phone[16]`, or in `int64_t`).